# Can this be done in O(logN) complexity?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

You are working on a project and you noticed that there has been a performance decrease between two releases. You have a function:

```
boolean worseCommit(int commit1, int commit2)
```

that runs performance tests and returns true if commit2 is worse than commit1 and false otherwise.

Find all of the bad commits that have decreased the performance between releases. 
Assume no improvement in performance.

Commit Id: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`

Performance: `10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 5, 5, 5`

Output `4, 7`

Comment: No it cannot be done in O(logN) because the size of the output is O(N) worst case.

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework question. How about you show some effort? What's your approach?

Comment: Ulrich: this isn’t a home work question :) I already solved this question in a linear time but was trying to optimize it.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done in O(k log(n/k)) and O(1) for k=0, where k is the number of slower releases. For a special case where there is exactly one bad release, it will take O(log n) operations.

Similarly to what n.m. has noted, if k=n or k is unspecified, then the runtime becomes O(n).

```
def bad_releases():
    slow = []
    add_slow(slow, 0, num_commits - 1)
    return slow

def add_slow(slow,  min, max)
    if not worseCommit(min, max):
        return
    if min + 1 = max:
        slow.append(max)
        return
    mid = (min + max) / 2
    add_slow(perf, slow, min, mid)
    add_slow(perf, slow, mid, max)
```

Note that insertions to `slow` run at most O(n) -- if every release got worse. Note that recursion does not continue into segments that have no slowdown.

We can know there is no slowdown, over a given interval, thanks to the fact that releases never get faster. So if both ends of the interval have the same performance, it means the whole interval has the same performance.

edit: using the supplied worseCommit function (instead of `performance` list), made the O expression tighter, fixed indentation, added clarification regarding O() for k=0, and fixed a typo (missing parameter).